# How to display a thumbnail with a mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, post, themes

I need your help because i'm stuck on one of my project. I'll explain :

I'm creating a WordPress theme and i want a page containing all of my post. [Check this image to see what i actually have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig5MC.png).
Each post has a thumbnail and i want the thumbnail which corresponds to the post to be hidden all the time and only appear when i do a mouseover. MouseOver on Post1 = Display of the Thumbnail of the Post1. MouseOver on Post2 = Display of the Thumbnail of the Post2.

You can see what i want on this link : http://nicholascope.com/sets

So actually, i have this but it's not working

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('h3[id^="lienImage"]').each(function(index){
                $(this).mouseover(function(){
                    $('div[class^="absolute"]').show();
                });
            })
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid text-light position-relative">
    {% for post in posts  %}
        <div class={{ "absolute" ~ loop.index }}  >
            <img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src }}"  alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-5 col-3">
                <a href="">
                    <h3 class="lienImage" id={{"lienImage" ~ loop.index }}>
                      {{post.title }}
                    </h3>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 ">
                <span class="lienImage">
                    {{ post.meta('clients') }}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks guys !!

Answer (score 0):

You could always use jquery and dynamic class selectors in order to create one function that could show/hide each section of your site by finding the closest hidden image in comparison to each p or div. See the example below.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('p').mouseover(function(){
        //Find sibling image to show in tooltip
        $img = $(this).closest('div').find('.thumbImage');
        // Put logic on show
        $img.fadeIn('slow');
   }).mouseout(function(){
        // Put logic on hide
        $img.fadeOut('slow');
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
  <div>
    <p>Sample text</p>
    <img class="thumbImage" style="display:none" src="sample.png" />
  </div>
   <div>
    <p>Sample text 2</p>
    <img class="thumbImage" style="display:none" src="sample.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Sample text 3</p>
    <img class="thumbImage" style="display:none" src="sample.png" />
  </div>
  </body> 
 </html>
```